# How do I attach VHD file to Oracle Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vhd

*Thanks* to [Update on Azure Storage Service Interruption | Microsoft Azure Blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/19/update-on-azure-storage-service-interruption/), my VM's Windows is failed to start and Microsoft suggested me downloading System's `.VHD` locally for troubleshooting (VM's system VHD is "Windows Server 2012 Datacenter"). According to: [Chapter 5. Virtual storage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails)

```
VirtualBox also fully supports the VHD format used by Microsoft.
```

I'm trying to do `Add Hard Disk` to newly created VM inside of VirtualBox and I'm getting following error:

**VirtualBox - Error**:

```
Could not get the storage format of the medium '/tmp/do1.vhd' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
```

&

```
Failed to open the hard disk file /tmp/do1.vhd.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '/tmp/do1.vhd' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

What am I doing wrong? and/or how to actually attach it to my VM?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very incomplete: which host and guest OSes are you running? What are you trying to do with the vhd image, build a VM on it, or just mount it?

If you are trying to use the disk do1.vhd as the main disk of a VM, you will find [here](http://www.macrium.com/help/v5/How_to/ImgToVHD/Create_a_virtual_machine_using_ImgToVHD.htm) very thorough instructions on how to do that.

If you are trying to mount the image from within the VM, the answer depends on your OS: on Linux you would do it [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295155/how-do-i-mount-vhd-file), using a package called virtualbox-fuse. If instead your guest OS is Windows, then you can do it [like this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/11/09/how_2d00_to_2d00_mount_2d00_vhd_2d00_image_2d00_from_2d00_windows_2d00_7_2d00_step_2d00_by_2d00_step_2d00_without_2d00_any_2d00_third_2d00_party_2d00_toolsthe_2d00_easy_2d00_way.aspx). Either operation has to be performed **within* the VM, which implies you will have to make the vhd file available to the VM, perhaps by sharing it.

Comment: I apologize for not being 100% clear, at this point all I want is to add Azure's `VHD` file to my local `VM` so I can start some troubleshooting.